# Reducing an array with nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have a array sorted by "src" and "target" as the following :

```
var sortedArr = [
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "B",
      "connection": "apple"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C"
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "pear"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "A",
      "connection": "pear"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
{
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "A",
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
{
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "apple"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  }
]
```

I need to keep only one of each "src" "target" pairs.
Each distinct pair will have a new property "connectionsArr" that is an array of all the distinct "connection" of pairs with identical "src" and "target".

It is just like if I reduced objects that have same "src" and "target" into only one object and concat their "connection" values into an array property called "connectionsArr".

In this example, I would need to obtain as result :

```
var sortedArr = [
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "B",
      "connection": "apple",
      "connectionsArr": ["apple"]
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
{
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "pear",
      "connectionsArr": ["banana","pear"]
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "A",
      "connection": "banana",
      "connectionsArr": ["pear","banana"]
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "apple",
      "connectionsArr": ["apple"]
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  }
  
]
```

Here is the function that needs to be reviewed :

```
  function removeDups(sortedArr ){

    for(var i = 1; i < sortedArr.length; ){
      sortedArr[i-1].orig.connArr = [sortedArr[i-1].orig.connection]
        if(sortedArr[i-1].orig.src === sortedArr[i].orig.src && sortedArr[i-1].orig.target === sortedArr[i].orig.target){
          sortedArr[i-1].orig.connArr.push(sortedArr[i].orig.connection)
            sortedArr.splice(i, 1);
            } else {
            i++;
            }
        }
    return sortedArr;
    }  

var linksOneLine = removeDups(links);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to handle your array (remove duplicates and connect them by `connectionArr` prop), see Code Snippet:

```js
const sortedArr = [
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "B",
      "connection": "apple"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "A",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "pear"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "A",
      "connection": "pear"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "A",
      "connection": "banana"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  },
  {
    "orig": {
      "src": "B",
      "target": "C",
      "connection": "apple"
    },
    "source": {},
    "target": {}
  }
];

const reducedArr = sortedArr.reduce((accum, item) => {
  // check if duplicate of item exist in accumulator
  let targIndex = -1;
  const accumOrig = accum.find((accItem, index) => {
    const isInAccum = (accItem.orig.src === item.orig.src && accItem.orig.target === item.orig.target);
    
    // get index of dulpicate in accumulator
    targIndex = isInAccum ? index : -1;
    return isInAccum;
  });
  
  // if duplicates of object not found
  if (!accumOrig) {
    // update item with new prop 'connectionArr'
    return [
      ...accum, {
        ...item,
        orig: {
          ...item.orig,
          connectionArr: [item.orig.connection]
        }
      }
    ];
  }
  
  // update accum item. Append connection from duplicate item
  const accumTmp = accum[targIndex].orig.connectionArr;

  const nextConnectionArr = accumTmp ? [...accumTmp, item.orig.connection] : [item.orig.connection];

  // remove duplicates of connection in array (connectionArr)
  accum[targIndex].orig.connectionArr = [...new Set(nextConnectionArr)];

  return accum;
}, []);

console.log('reducedArr:', reducedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simpler approach to your function and do the following

```
let result = sortedArr.filter((prev, index) => {
    return sortedArr.findIndex((x) => {
    return x.orig.target == prev.orig.target && x.orig.src == prev.orig.src;}) == index;

});
```

You can view the result on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/FDBuEMCcAIGcHtIBcCmATAgpGBeaBtYaaAbyOOgCJEBLAc0oC5TyKrZIBjJqjSgGlYVKSKHRRIelAEIChxSp3gA7ZSk5IaKqeAAOugDYpKQgL6C2lBAFcux5iXNCRYiT0fknxMpdoMH8uxcUnwWbFSikOKSzJQAwnLhVEqq6prasQBG4Mo54CZsXsI2du5FCpHRZZ5hPsJ%207oFWwbGhTZVusQlhlilqGlrKUtm5uQUU5ezwtpz2pJMuUZ3zNeR1Cg0BSc3crYnhi1Vd%2070q-elDsbooUOPECyWzZT0RrjEr97XOmyzbHLtUWQvCpvEInYR9NKDKTXW5mF5WaalBwLDrvDyfYDrKg-bEKf5SIHtUF7YHJM5QjJUEZ5O7QB5Ip4ohFo6qY7HUSD0Rp-FqA8EgpbveIC8mpAZUyh6QzGeHOR5zRwskkfenAAC6ICMSGgkBQsGsBh1eAQyHQWEgADoAGY0I0oSAACkdKH40BoAEpoDgAHy-Ch6pC2ZRwRCoTDYG00ZRoACSMZQAA9nYmvb7-cRA8HoInLX5LWjvXgUHmuXQC29oAAyKs50v0S3-IvQEv5-4AblMabwNHbIC7feAKQQRktBngdEdeoNRo9QA)

By the way you can remove those returns if you want since returning from the arrow function without the curly braces reaches the same goal, the returns were to help you follow each logical step. Like this:

```
let result = sortedArr.filter((prev, index) => 
    sortedArr.findIndex((x) => 
        x.orig.target == prev.orig.target && x.orig.src == prev.orig.src) == index
)
```